# How can i install team viewer in ubuntu 16 operating system

Tags: ubuntu, teamviewer

As i need to install team viewer to my local pc which has ubuntu 16 in it .Can i get steps for how to install team viewer in ubuntu16 operating system .

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a good start would be to download the .deb from here
[teanviewer deb](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux/)

and read the help file here
[help](https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/How-do-I-install-TeamViewer-on-my-Linux-distribution/ta-p/4351#toc-hId-764334519)